# Google Classroom: I don't see any students grades

Tags: google-classroom

How do we see students grades after their completion of the test? I don't see their grades. Please suggest some setting or something from where I can see grades.

Answer (score 0):

1. Once you create and assign a question / quiz, the students can see it and answer

---

[image]

---

[image]

2. You as the the teacher can view the question and student submissions

---

[image]

---

[image]

3. Grade the student and return

---

[image]

---

4. Go to `Grades` and view the results

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But after clicking any particular student I cannot see his response anywhere so how can I grade somebody?

Comment: In short, how we can identify any students reply and return them any grade from that response!

Comment: Or Is there settings where they get their grades automatically just after the submission of the test/Quiz? This will be even great.

Comment: If you click on a student with the `Turned in`  status, his answer will be visible on the right side of the window (in the screenshot the students answer is `This is the answer`). If a student has the status `assigned`, it means that he did not submit a response yet. Which kind of assignment are you working with? If you have a `Google Forms quiz`, you can enable automatic `assign points` and `automatic feedback`: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7032287?hl=en

Comment: Yes, When I clicked on a student with the turned in status his answer/response are not visible to me. And I enable the automatic assign points option also but nothing happened. Something somewhere is missing. 
My assignment is of simple MCQ.

Comment: Do students need to submit in another way so that we can view their submission? They are just checking their answers and submitting that's it, Is anything more they have to do? I don't think so. What're your suggestions.

Comment: If you want automatic grading, than you need to create the assignment as 'Quiz assignment' and make sure to activate 'Grade importing'. Later , when you go on  'View assignment' - click on 'Import grades'.

Comment: From where we find "Grade importing" option? And my assignment is quiz assignment.

Comment: When you click on view assignment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t46zBgtD3AUH-zD09VfmkXoBKuYTSHDv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: No, I don't find such an option on my quiz assignment!

Comment: When you created the quiz assignement, did you activate `Grade importing` : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C0f9JeRwj-BaJ3XXbabQbHpVPURa-0U6/view?usp=sharing